# How to add an array from static void main to a combobox in @override

Tags: java, arrays, javafx

I'm importing data from a text file so I am using the static void main area to create an array there that collects information from my text file.

How can I get this array that I created in `public static void main` over here to the `loanTermComboBox.getItems().addAll();`?

```
@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        btCancel.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
            System.exit(0);
        });
        btCalculate.setOnAction(e -> calculateLoanPayment());

        GridPane pane = new GridPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 800, 300);
        loanTermComboBox = new ComboBox();
        interestRateComboBox = new ComboBox<>();


        loanTermComboBox.getItems().addAll(
        "1", "2"
        );
```

Comment: Just create the array in `start()` instead

Comment: Or create it in the `init()` method.

Comment: I didn't realize it got the data on it's own. Any idea how I can get the array into my loanTermComboBox? I tired putting it in         loanTermComboBox = new ComboBox(array);  but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Just check if the array has data in it. Just asking, is array a Collection?

Comment: What does "it got the data on its own" mean?

Comment: I was able to figure it out, but thank you! What I meant by that earlier is that I didn't realize in the public void start that it would go through the while loop on it's own. I thought it had to have an action event linked to it before it actually started going through the while loop to get data for my array.